# Loading UIViewController in UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using a swipe gesture code to flip an image, which calls this code:

```
- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    for (UIImageView *imageView in imageArray)
    {

        if (([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && imageView.tag == ((UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer).view.tag))
        {
            [UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                       //imageView.image = secondImage;
                   } completion:^(BOOL f){
                       UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PhotoViewControllerStoryboard" bundle:nil];
                       UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
                       vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
                       [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
                       vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(343, 163, 316, 546.5);

                }
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

The flip works correctly, but when the animation is over, the view controller loads in a black background. I want it to load in the `UIImage` like if it was the backside of the image. How can I do this??

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot? I do not exactly know what you mean. Maybe your views background is black?

Comment: can I set it to transparent? See the edit

Comment: You could set its bg color to clearColor for example. Is the frame of the added view controller really like your rect? I think (so not sure) presentViewController is presenting it as a ModalVC.
Your could try adding it as subview of your current view controller (self addChildViewController:vc] and [imageView.addSubview:vc.view]

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work